# check only the first XX number of lines of a var for a string

Tags: python, html, lines

Hey i got the following code:

```
import urllib

source = urllib.urlopen('WEBPAGE').read()
if 'STRING TO LOOK FOR' in source:
    print 'MESSAGE'
else:
    print 'else MESSAGE'
```

which checks a webpage source code for a specific string, is there a way that only the first lets say 20 lines of the code get searched through for the string? and if the string is not in there i get the else Message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `if 'STRING TO LOOK FOR' in source:` to

```
if 'STRING TO LOOK FOR' in '\n'.join(source.split('\n', 20)[:20]):
```

Split the source into lines and then reassemble the first 20 lines.